# posting data from a razor generated table

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I have a table filled with generated data using razor. Each row has the id of the PlanID in the database.

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var plan in ViewBag.plans) {
        <tr id="@plan.PlanID">
            <td contenteditable="true">@plan.Name</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">@plan.Code</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">@plan.Description</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">@plan.DataAmount</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">@plan.Price</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">@plan.SmartPhoneCost</td>
            <td><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

I have also made button click append the table with a new row to add a plan

```
    function Add() {
        $("#tableData tbody").append(
            "<tr role='form' action='/api/wirelessplans' method='post'>" +
            "<td><input name='Name' type='text' size='30' maxlength='30'/></td>" +
            "<td><input name='Code' type='text' /></td>" +
            "<td><input name='Description' type='text' size='50' maxlength='50'/></td>" +
            "<td><input name='DataAmount' type='text' /></td>" +
            "<td><input name='Price' type='text' /></td>" +
            "<td><input name='SmartPhoneCost' type='text' /></td>" +
            "<td><a class='save' type='submit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></a></td>" +
            "</tr>")

    };

    $(function () {
        $("body").on("click", ".addPlan", function () {
            Add()

        });
    });
```

I have made the the td's editable and would like to click on the icon to submit the changes to -- api/wirelessplans/ that I defined in my controller.   How do I grab only the values that are changed (or added in the new row) and post/put to the database?

Comment: I don't see a specific question here, where are you having trouble?

Comment: Why not store the original value of the elements into an attribute, so you can simply compare them for changes and only send those that are different?